# Display array data only one time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array which looks like below -

```js
const arr = [{name: 'ST', value: 1}, {value: 0}, {name: 'ST', value: 2}]
```

I'm looping over above `arr` with the `map` function and able to display the value.

But the problem is I want to display name only single time. For e.g. `ST: 3`.

So `ST` will display single time and we will do the addition of all the value.
Also I dont know the index of name at which index it is available.

Is there any other alternative for this rather doing hardcode `name`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns an array and not suitable in your use case. You can use `forEach`, `reduce` or normal `for-loop`. The below code achieves the result using `reduce`. Inside callback function sum all the values.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'ST',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'ST',
  value: 0
}, {
  name: 'ST',
  value: 2
}].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.name]) {
    acc[curr.name] = curr.value;

  } else {
    acc[curr.name] += curr.value
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: what about name? I want to display name from this array.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava how your final output look like?

Comment: final output will be like `ST: 3`

Comment: @AtalShrivastavain form of string or object?

Comment: Actually i'm using react here, So i want to display this info in the UI. Currently I'm using map function to return data which display ST two times because it present two times in the array

Comment: it does not answer my question

Comment: String would be fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achive this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [{ name: "ST", value: 1 }, { value: 0 }, { name: "ST", value: 2 }];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name, value } = curr;
  const tempSearchObj = acc.find((o) => o.name === name);
  if (tempSearchObj) {
    tempSearchObj.value = value + tempSearchObj.value;
  } else {
    if (name) acc = [...acc, { name, value }];
    else acc = [...acc, { value }];
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you use `Array.map` the length of the `output array` will be same as the length of the `input array`. So, that is not the desired method that you want.

There are multiple ways in achieving the desired output. As you want to display the sum of all the `values` where you've the same `name` then `Array.reduce` will come to the rescue.

```js
const arr = [{name: 'ST', value: 1}, {value: 0}, {name: 'ST', value: 2}]

const formatArr = arr => {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((res, obj) => {
  //Check if the object is already present in the accumulator i.e., res
  //If so, add he current obj.value to the existing value
    if(res[obj.name]) {
      res[obj.name].value += obj.value;
    } else {
    //else create a new object and add it the accumulator
      res[obj.name] = {...obj}
    }
    return res;
  }, {}));
}

//Get the formatted array with cumulative values based on name
const formattedOutput = formatArr(arr);
//Use loop to print values. 
//If you are using react you can use `map` to display in the UI.
//For simplicity here i'm using `forEach` to display in the console.
formattedOutput.forEach(obj => {
  console.log(`${obj.name || "Name"}: ${obj.value}`);
})
```